# Spectral Flow​ vs. Edge currents in the integer quantum Hall effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, quantum-hall-effect

In the integer quantum Hall effect, there are at least two perspectives given in the scientific literature, which are related. One picture is from the Laughlin-Halperin construction where we imagine that extended states undergo spectral flow. The other picture is concerned with edge states, where the confining potential of the solid leads to transverse currents. My question is this: the Laughlin-Halperin picture gives a description where the charge seems to be transferred through the bulk, whereas the currents in the edge state picture seem to be confined to the edges. Which picture is correct and are they consistent with each other?